# Would ABRSM accept scores from SheetMusicDirect or SheetMusicPlus in exams?

Tags: sheet-music, abrsm

If you entered candidates into ABRSM exams would scores purchased from [SheetMusicDirect](https://help.sheetmusicdirect.com/hc/en-us) or [SheetMusicPlus](https://www.sheetmusicplus.com/) be acceptable for exam purposes? The scores have a watermark with your details on it. These two websites also pay all required royalties to artist and arrangers. Has there been any official correspondence from ABRSM on whether legally purchased scores from these sites will be accepted in exam venues?

Comment: Surely the best place to pose this question is with ABRSM themselves. They're very amenable, and will give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/information-and-regulations/ says

> Sheet music obtained via digital download may be read from an electronic device in the exam. Devices must be switched off, except when being used for this purpose, and should never be used to record any part of the exam.

This would *suggest* that it's also valid in printed form. But it might be like trying to board an airplane with a nail clipper: if the person at the door disagrees, even if they're in the wrong, there's not much you can do about it besides go home. I would suggest getting written confirmation.